# How would I normalization nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalization

I have been trying to normalize this nested json , being on it for two days now and no productive output,I have tried going the extra mile ,read documentation but no show. I will appreciate extra hands and expertises.
Thank you.

These are the list of fields I am trying to get out;

1. clusterTime
2. documnetKey
3. fulldocument.buzName
4. fulldocument.dealType'
5. fulldocument.Companies'
6. fulldocument.Sub_companies'
7. fulldocument.Directories
8. term
9. 'operationType'

```
{'_id': {'_data': '826019AB3C000000012B0'},
 'clusterTime': Timestamp(1612294972, 1),
 'documentKey': {'_id': ObjectId('5b7cfc0172cb100011ddadfb')},
 'fullDocument': {'buzName': 'Market',
                  'v': 29,
                  '_id': ObjectId('5b7cfc0172cb100011ddadfb'),
                  'addersValues': [],
                  'contractType': 'C & I',
                  'Volume': 54.04637908572,
                  'VolumeUOM': 'MWh',
                  'dealType': 'New',
                  'Companies': [{'Number': '002093834',
                                  'DC': 'flex',
                                  '_id': ObjectId('5b555555cb100011dde53e'),
                                  'FlowEnd': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 21, 0, 0),
                                  'FlowStart': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 22, 0, 0),
                                  'profile': 'SERVICE_NORTH',
                                  'rateCode': 'DC'}],
                  'government': False,
                  'heatRate': None,
                  'Sub_companies': [{'Number': '1000002093834',
                                  'DC': 'easy',
                                  '_id': ObjectId('5b555555cb100011dde53e'),
                                  'FlowEnd': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 21, 0, 0),
                                  'FlowStart': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 22, 0, 0),
                                  'profile': 'SERVICE_NORTH',
                                  'rateCode': 'DC'}],
                  'heatRateIndex': None,
                  'heatRateUOM': None,
                  'TexasTIndex': None,
                  'MaxEnd': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 21, 0, 0),
                  'originaldate': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 12, 5, 0),
                  'originator': 'Luke',
                  'parentCustomerName': None,
                  'Directories': ['TEXAS_AdminFeeInc_PT', 'TXLZ_PT'],
                  'term': 12,
                  'voluntaryRECPerc': None,
                  'voluntaryRECs': False,
                  'westRTIndex': None},
  'operationType': 'update'}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, is this mongodb data (`ObjectId`)? What is `Timestamp`?

Comment: Yeah this is a mongoldb data,

Comment: `Companies`, `Directories`, and `Sub_companies` are lists, how do you want to flatten those if there is more than one item?

Comment: Honestly, this is my first first of dealing with normalizing json in python.  This is what I have tried                                                                                            for output in watchdeal.find():
    print(pd.json_normalize(output,['fullDocument',['Companies','Sub_companies','Directories','dealType']] ,meta=['operationType','term','clusterTime','documnetKey'])

Comment: problem is, it appears you have three record objects: `Companies`, `Directories`, and `Sub_companies`, the decision you need to make is how you want to handle these lists inside your data. If there is only one record item, it is a lot easier, but if you only expect one nested record in these, it makes it easier.

Comment: I am not an expert with these normalization, But I am kind of thinking is having them as a separate dataFrame and then inner join.I tried =>  print(pd.json_normalize(output,['fullDocument',['Companies']])) it outputted only the companies, but I couldn't add the meta data, like documentKey , which I am thinking, I could use to join the separate frames.

Comment: you could do this at your mongodb query step, or if you want traditional, flat, table-based structure you can use mongodb bi connector

Comment: "read documentation" is not "going the extra mile", it is taking the 1st step. PS Please clarify via edits, not commments. PS [mre]

Comment: BI connector would have been the best , but I kind of have restricted access,. Do you have an simple template for this normalization which I can build on.

Comment: Possibly @TenaciousB didn't get notification of your last comment, since after my comment there were multiple non-poster commenters & you didn't use `@`. (But they'll get notification of this comment.)

Comment: @philipxy I really appreciate you trying to help, the code/ json provide is the least I can go, I have really done alot of filtering at the same time  trying not  to loss the  context of the issue I am trying to solve.Like I said above the is my first normalization experience. I really would appreciate your help . Thank you.

Comment: is that json the RESPONSE of a mongodb query?

Comment: @TenaciousB that is an output of a changeStream query in mognodb

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried, I isolated each embedded object with an aggregation pipeline starting with **Companies**  and hope to do the same for **subcompanies** and then  **directories**  then join by documentKey.

```
for output in watchdeal.aggregate([{"$project":{"_id":0,"operationType":1,"clusterTime":1,'documentKey':1,"fullDocument":{"buzName":1},"facilities":"$fullDocument.Companies"}}]):
    print(pd.json_normalize(output,'Companies',["clusterTime","documentKey","operationType",['fullDocument','buzName']]))
```